# Sync specific folders with Grive

Tags: linux, google-drive

Is there any way to only sync specific folders when using Grive2 and Grive-tools?

The regular windows google drive gives you this option in the preferences menu but that doesn't appear to be available with Grive for linux. By the looks of it grive-tools just syncs everything. Is there maybe some 'hacky' way to change this via editing config files or something?

If it isn't possible with Grive, then is there another linux google drive app which does offer this option?